# Using php and mysql with jquery bMap

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, google-maps

For a university project I am creating a website that helps you find golf courses around Ireland & N.Ireland. I have done this using bMap - jquery and google maps. You can choose a county from a sidebar and be shown it on the map. I have used the following code to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#map").bMap({
        mapZoom: 8,
        mapCenter:[53.65115,    -8.81104],
        mapSidebar:"sideBar", //id of the div to use as the sidebar
        markers:{"data":[
                {"lat":"54.66625","lng":"-6.28647","title":"County Antrim","rnd":"1","body":"There are 38 golf clubs in County Antrim, <a href='counties/antrim.html'>View here</a>"},

                {"lat":"54.29401","lng":"-6.66592","title":"County Armagh","rnd":"1","body":"There are 8 golf clubs in County Armagh, <a href='counties/armagh.html'>View here</a>"},
```

What I am wondering is there a way I can create a database and use php/mysql to show the same results. I need it to be County Antrim, County Armagh, etc.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is it hard to do? Not very experienced with this stuff, any way you could explain it a bit please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the courses in the database with the columns required such as latitude, longitude, title, rnd, body.
Then build a string with them, and reference that in the JavaScript code.

```
$course_data = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM golf_courses";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $course_data .= '{"lat":"' . $row['latitude'] . '","lng":"' . $row['longitude'] . '","title":"' . $row['title'] . '","rnd":"' . $row['rnd'] . '","body":"' . $row['body'] . '"},'
}
```

And then in your code, reference the course_data variable, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#map").bMap({
        mapZoom: 8,
        mapCenter:[53.65115,    -8.81104],
        mapSidebar:"sideBar", //id of the div to use as the sidebar
        markers:{"data":[
                <?php echo $course_data; ?>
```

Remember this is an example and will need some playing around with to get the database tables right etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, ill try that.

Then say the first one 'Antrim' has 38 golf courses within it, is there a way I can display those results once I have clicked on that specific county?

Comment: So are you showing a marker at every golf course, but you only want it for when you click on a certain area? So by default, no markers are there, but when you click 'Antrim' for example it loads the map with markers at all Antrim golf courses?

Comment: No I have a google map on my home page with 32 markers (one for each county), placing the markers on the page using the code above. I want it when you click on a county it will then bring you to a different page showing you the php/mysql results of the different golf courses within that county. For example antrim has 32, armagh has 8, etc. Sorry didnt explain that very well.

Comment: In that case, instead of storing golf courses in the database you would store the counties, and for the 'body' value of each of those counties you would include the link to the page which displays information on the county.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, get you now. Thanks so much for your help. Really appreciate it :)